# ragged right side in \itemize

Tags: itemize, justification

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[efficiency] The ledenn and isolatiosdfsf sdfdsy is mead using the tag-and-probe method~\ref{fig:a}. This method uses owasdfn mass diasdf-sdfobjt redfnances Sadstudy electallk symme breallking and s\
edarch or he ggh. asfasdf  ererer tyerher hhtyh eertyhrty gfbfghh erthgfha rwer  wwerewr dfdsfdsgf tewrtert rdjty jejtyj  rhrtrth ryreyrt jtythw. etewrt tert . weterte hHig in Fig. the Hig
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A}
  \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The text output is:

[image]

Why is the first line in item "efficiency" salient? It seems Latex there has plenty of freedom to make the right side justified.

Comment: While it may seem so, TeX disagrees with your assessment.  Try adding `\sloppy` to your preamble and see the problem disappear...at the expense of large word gaps.  **NOTE: you have disabled the hyphenation of `method`**

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the gaps seem much more innocuous  than a line sticking out.

Comment: The line justification algorithm is all about assigning penalties and minimizing the objective function.  If gaps are not objectionable, then redefining the penalties is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hyphenation of the word `method` has been disabled by following it with a hard space.  You have two options: manually reinsert a hyphenation point, or put up with wider gaps associated with `\sloppy` or `sloppypar`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[efficiency] The ledenn and isolatiosdfsf sdfdsy is mead using the tag-and-probe me\-thod~\ref{fig:a}. This method uses owasdfn mass diasdf-sdfobjt redfnances Sadstudy electallk symme breallking and s\
edarch or he ggh. asfasdf  ererer tyerher hhtyh eertyhrty gfbfghh erthgfha rwer  wwerewr dfdsfdsgf tewrtert rdjty jejtyj  rhrtrth ryreyrt jtythw. etewrt tert . weterte hHig in Fig. the Hig
\end{itemize}

\sloppy
\begin{itemize}
\item[efficiency] The ledenn and isolatiosdfsf sdfdsy is mead using the tag-and-probe method~\ref{fig:a}. This method uses owasdfn mass diasdf-sdfobjt redfnances Sadstudy electallk symme breallking and s\
edarch or he ggh. asfasdf  ererer tyerher hhtyh eertyhrty gfbfghh erthgfha rwer  wwerewr dfdsfdsgf tewrtert rdjty jejtyj  rhrtrth ryreyrt jtythw. etewrt tert . weterte hHig in Fig. the Hig
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A}
  \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed this problem only in the `itemize` environment. Could it be possible also in the main text?

Comment: @Viesturs The exact same problem is possible in main text as well.  However, since `itemize` has a narrower column width, the problem is more likely there.